# Linux to Windows File Attributes

Tags: windows, filesystems, redhat-enterprise-linux, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to move files from Linux File Server (RHEL 5.5) to Windows 2012r2 and maintain timestamp and owner? Is this possible?

Comment: If the files have ACLs, then the owner will be preserved (usually, haven't tried). About the timestamp: which one? Last Access, Last Modified, Created?

Comment: Sorry, I must have been asleep when I posted this. The files are are not on the same domain so there is no trust associated with them.